# How to get Blob from files uploaded from material-ui-dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, blob, file-read

I'm struggling with the following problem:

I am using `material-ui-dropzone` as a file uploader in my react project.
Here is the `DropZone` component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { DropzoneArea } from 'material-ui-dropzone';

class DropZone extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const {handleFile} = this.props
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div>
          <DropzoneArea
            showPreviews={true}
            showPreviewsInDropzone={false}
            useChipsForPreview
            previewGridProps={{container: { spacing: 1, direction: 'row' }}}
            previewText="Selected files"
            onChange={handleFile}
            filesLimit={1}
            showPreviews
            maxSize={500000000}
          />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default DropZone;
```

The `handleFile` function is defined as:

```
  handleFile(loadedFiles) {
    console.log(loadedFiles)
    this.setState({file: loadedFiles})

    var file = loadedFiles[0];
    console.log('file', file)

    var reader = new FileReader();
    console.log('reader', reader)

    reader.onload = function(file) {
      console.log('1')
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      var kb = byteArray.length / 1024;
      var mb = kb / 1024;
      console.log('kb', kb)
      console.log('mb', mb)

      var dataSet;
      dataSet = dicomParser.parseDicom(byteArray);
      console.log(dataSet)
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  }
```

The issue is that when I upload a file, the error shows:

`TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

This is pretty obvious. It says that the input argument in `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)` is not Blob, but `readAsArrayBuffer` expects a Blob. Therefore any code in `reader.onload()` is not executed.

If I comment out the `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)` line and console log prints the uploaded file (which is `file`, or `loadedFiles[0]` in the code), I can see the following:

```
File {path: "1.2.840.113619.2.416.2007613730195585237539498016923856630.2", name: "1.2.840.113619.2.416.2007613730195585237539498016923856630.2", lastModified: 1581235163000, lastModifiedDate: Sun Feb 09 2020 16:59:23 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
lastModified: 1581235163000
lastModifiedDate: Sun Feb 09 2020 16:59:23 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) {}
name: "1.2.840.113619.2.416.2007613730195585237539498016923856630.2"
path: "1.2.840.113619.2.416.2007613730195585237539498016923856630.2"
size: 526884
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
lastModified: (...)
lastModifiedDate: (...)
name: (...)
size: (...)
type: (...)
webkitRelativePath: (...)
constructor: ƒ File()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "File"
get lastModified: ƒ lastModified()
get lastModifiedDate: ƒ lastModifiedDate()
get name: ƒ name()
get webkitRelativePath: ƒ webkitRelativePath()
__proto__: Blob
```

This is the object that `DropzoneArea` of `material-ui-dropzone` is giving me. Is this a Blob? How can I make a Blob out of this?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else looking to figure this our there is a `prop` called `onDrop` This works like `onchange` and gives you the file, and event. Read the 2nd `event` argument which allows access to target files. use the onDrop and pass the 2nd argument as event.

```js
  handleUpload(files, event) {
   
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const text = e.target.result;
      console.log(typeof text);
      alert(text);
    };
    reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
}




 <DropzoneArea
        onDrop={(files, event) => this.handleUpload(files, event)}
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to use a FileReader.
This is what I did in order to get a byteArray from the Files sent by the DropZone.onDrop() event:

```
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
          if (!!reader.result) {
             let result = new Uint8Array(reader.result as ArrayBuffer));
             return result;

          }
      }
      reader.onerror = (error) => {
         return error;
      }
```

In this case, result would contain the byteArray needed. If you want the file data in a different kind of steam, you can another of the `reader` functions available instead of `readAsArrayBuffer(file)`;